# LINQ doesnt work for japanese words

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

I have list of items defined as: `IQueryable` and I need go trough and find if any of the fields contain a specific word. When I use foreach and loop trough it and use `.Contains`, then everything works fine. The problem is that I need to use LINQ and `.Boost`, because some of the fields have higher priority when I find words in them.
When I use LINQ I get no results. For most languages LINQ works fine, but for Japanese words it does not. Can someone explain me why foreach with .Contains works fine and LINQ with .Where does not?

Code example:

```
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            if ((item.PageHeadings != null && item.PageHeadings.Contains(keyword)) ||
                (item.PageName != null && item.PageName.Contains(keyword)) ||
                (item.MetadataDescription != null &&
                 item.MetadataDescription.Contains(keyword)) ||
                (item.MetadataKeywords != null &&
                 item.MetadataKeywords.Contains(keyword)) ||
                (item.ExpandedContent != null &&
                 item.ExpandedContent.Contains(keyword)))
            {

                list.Add(item.Name);
            }

        }
```

LINQ example:

```
         list.AddRange(from item in itemList where (item.PageHeadings != null 
    && item.PageHeadings.Contains(keyword).Boost(BoostPageHeading)) 
    || (item.PageName != null && item.PageName.Contains(keyword).Boost(BoostPageName)) 
    || (item.MetadataDescription != null && item.MetadataDescription.Contains(keyword).Boost(BoostMetadataDescription)) 
|| (item.MetadataKeywords != null && item.MetadataKeywords.Contains(keyword).Boost(BoostMetadataKeywords)) 
    || (item.ExpandedContent != null && item.ExpandedContent.Contains(keyword).Boost(BoostExpandedContent)) select item.Name);
```

Thanks

UPDATE:
Example of phrase: 天窓使用例

Comment: you'are talking about Japanese and why not show some Japanese in your code?

Comment: Can you post simpler code samples that we can try? Those posted does not help us at all.See [MCVE]

Comment: That´s not what I´d condsider an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try evaluating each condition against the input and identifying which condition is not matching.

Comment: Japanese characters are unicode (two bytes) while most languages only use one byte characters.  The linq should work with both one and two bytes characters.  So the issue is usually where you are read the input(s) from a file. The stream that is reading either the input of the keyword must be changes to specify unicode encoding.

Comment: @jdweng a .net character is always two-bytes in size, though they may be surrogate pairs (they mostly will not with Japanese text though).

Comment: @Jon Hanna sure, utf16le chars can hold japanese alphabets (i'm not too sure about glyphs). The chance of input corruption is still a valid issue though (we don't know what file does the author use).

Comment: The two samples are not identical to each other. One contains a method named _boost_ but other not. Maybe it works wrong. Can you share also that method?

Comment: Jon : What you said is not exactly correct and misleading.  I didn't want to get into the details, but there is a private property that indicates if the character is one or two bytes.  The encoding methods have access to set the private property.  So when the private property is set to one byte the character is only one byte.